# Accessing CSS Constants in GWT UiBinder Style

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

Using GWT 2.1, I am trying to create a CSS file that contains numerous constants and common styles. I would like to use the ui:style tag to include it in the UiBinder template:

```
<ui:UiBinder
  xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
  xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'

  <ui:style field="css" src="constants.css" />
</ui:UiBinder>
```

I can easily utilize the styles for elements:

```
<g:FlowPanel styleName="{css.panel}">...</g:FlowPanel>
```

But attempting to use the constants in another Style block fails:

```
<ui:Style>
  .templateSpecificStyle {
      background-color: {css.royalBlue};
      padding: 1em;
  }
</ui:Style>
```

Oddly I do not receive a compile error. The obfuscated CSS class is created; however, the content is empty. Is there any way to access these CSS constants within another Style block? Is it possible using the older ResourceBundle / CssResource pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After re-reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533211/need-app-wide-css-constants-in-gwt/4143017#4143017 I see that the constants work if you add the template specific style within the style block:

```
<ui:Style src="constants.css">
  .templateSpecificStyle {
      background-color: royalBlue;
      padding: 1em;
  }
</ui:Style>
```

This is perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 4):

It may be in your best interest to define these constants in some class, then use runtime substitution to include this constant in each CSS resource you intend to use.

**CSSConstants.java**

```
package com.foo.client;
public final class CSSConstants {
    public static final String ROYAL_BLUE = "#4169E1";
}
```

**Style block in UiBinder template**

```
<ui:style>
  @eval royalBlue com.foo.client.ROYAL_BLUE
  .templateSpecificStyle {
    background-color: royalBlue
  }
</ui:style>
```

Note that even the name of the technique is "runtime substitution", the GWT compiler will replace `royalBlue` with a string literal because the value of `royalBlue` can be evaluated at compile time.

For more cool stuff that you can do in CSS resources, take a look at http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#CssResource

Comment: It seems really verbose, and somewhat ugly, to @eval each of the constants I wish to reference in each UiBinder template. The constants.css also contains a few useful styles. I am really hoping there is a cleaner way. The <ui:style src> is an incredibly nice feature because it automatically generates the interfaces.

Comment: I agree - a lot of GWT stuff can get quite verbose at times. An alternative approach is to extend the `CssResource` interface so that you can expose the constants that way. This would save you from creating `CSSConstants.java`. However, you'd still need an `@eval` to get those styles where they need to go.