# How can I use the same @def in multiple CssResource css files?

Tags: gwt, cssresource, clientbundle

I'd like to say, in a single, centralized location,

```
@def mainColor = #f00;
```

and then, in all of my other css files, refer to `mainColor` without having to redefine it.  Then when I change mainColor in once place, my entire app changes color.

The best way I can think of so far is to include two `@Source` files for every CssResource declaration and always include the global def file.  Are there any other ways?

Comment: Could you please add your own @Source example as another 'answer' for comparison?

Comment: I just added it as a comment to Danny Kirchmeier's answer below.  It's essentially the same technique, with a different syntax and context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, this is your only option:

**style.css**

```
@def mainColor #f00;
```

***.ui.xml**

```
<ui:style src="../../../styles/style.css">
    .widget{ color: mainColor; }
</ui:style>
```

The downside to this is the relative path. Each ui.xml will require a different src path.

Alternatively, if you dont mind using a Constants.java file (instead of css), 
you could use `@eval`

```
<ui:style>
  @eval mainColor com.myproject.client.Styles.INSTANCE.mainColor(); 
  .widget{ color: mainColor; }
</ui:style>
```

Comment: Oof.  Thanks for the suggestions.  These are pretty rough, though ;)

Comment: @Thomas Broyer added at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-web-toolkit/c8XdDoxDNZA/dWtkdAENYXMJ that he uses this method, too.  Outside of uibinders he mentioned the multiple @Source technique: `@Source({"path/to/definitions.css", "foo.css"}) FooStyles foo;`