# How can I use a Generator to modify a css file for a CssResource?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

I am using GWT Generators and want to modify a css file with a Generator. The css file contains constants like the following (test/client/App.css):

```
@def LINE_WIDTH 100px;
```

I defined an interface (test/client/DeviceDensity.java):

```
public interface DeviceDensity extends CssResource {

    String APP_CSS = "test/client/App.css";

}
```

Using a gwt generator I want to modify the constant **LINE_WIDTH** to be either 75px, 100px, 150px or 200px; depending on the value of a property **phone.density** which is defined in a module file as:

```
    <define-property name="phone.density" values="lpdi,mdpi,hpdi,xhdpi" />
    <property-provider name="phone.density"><![CDATA[
    {
        var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio;
        if (ratio == 0.75) { return "lpdi"; }
        else if (ratio == 1) {return "mdpi"; }
        else if (ratio == 1.5) {return "hpdi"; }
        return "xhdpi";
    }
    ]]></property-provider>
```

**How can I get the value of phone.density in a Generator and how can I modify the css constant LINE_WIDTH?**

Comment: Is the issue resolved?

Comment: @Braj No, how do I generate a new css file?

Comment: Are you able to get the value of phone.density in a Generator [Java Code]?

Comment: @Braj getting the value of phone.density is easy.

Comment: OK Great. Sorry I don't have any idea about Generator.

Answer (score 0):

**How can I get the value of phone.density in a Generator?**

Possibly not as simple as you wanted, but you can do something like this:

- Create a base class `com.gwt.demo.client.PhoneDensity` and subclasses one for each value of phone density as shown below.

  ```
  public class PhoneDensity {}

  public class PhoneDensityLpdi extends PhoneDensity{}
  public class PhoneDensityMdpi extends PhoneDensity{}
  public class PhoneDensityHpdi extends PhoneDensity{}
  public class PhoneDensityXhdpi extends PhoneDensity{}
  ```
- Add this to your gwt.xml:

  ```
      <define-property name="density" values="lpdi,mdpi,hpdi,xhdpi" />

      <property-provider name="density"><![CDATA[
      {
          var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio;
          if (ratio == 0.75) { return "lpdi"; }
          else if (ratio == 1) {return "mdpi"; }
          else if (ratio == 1.5) {return "hpdi"; }
          return "xhdpi";
      }
      ]]></property-provider>

      <replace-with class="com.gwt.demo.client.PhoneDensityLpdi">
          <when-type-is class="com.gwt.demo.client.PhoneDensity" />
          <when-property-is name="density" value="lpdi" />
      </replace-with>

      <replace-with class="com.gwt.demo.client.PhoneDensityMdpi">
          <when-type-is class="com.gwt.demo.client.PhoneDensity" />
          <when-property-is name="density" value="mdpi" />
      </replace-with>

      <replace-with class="com.gwt.demo.client.PhoneDensityHpdi">
          <when-type-is class="com.gwt.demo.client.PhoneDensity" />
          <when-property-is name="density" value="hpdi" />
      </replace-with>

      <replace-with class="com.gwt.demo.client.PhoneDensityXhdpi">
          <when-type-is class="com.gwt.demo.client.PhoneDensity" />
          <when-property-is name="density" value="xhdpi" />
      </replace-with>
  ```
- In your client-side code:

  ```
      // this is the magical line to read the phone density
      PhoneDensity phoneDensity = GWT.create(PhoneDensity.class);

      String density = null;
      if (phoneDensity instanceof PhoneDensityLpdi) {
          density = "lpdi";
      } else if (phoneDensity instanceof PhoneDensityMdpi) {
          density = "mdpi";
      } else if (phoneDensity instanceof PhoneDensityHpdi) {
          density = "hpdi";
      } else {
          density = "xhdpi";
      }
  ```

> You'll get an instance of `PhoneDensity` based on the value of phone density.

- **Done**

---

**Read the section [Elements for Deferred Binding](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html).**

For detailed discussion on the above approach please have a look at below thread

- [Get value of GWT property at runtime](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/4G5boPma_h0).

---

**How can I modify the css constant LINE_WIDTH?**

Now you have the value of phone density in your client side JAVA code. Move this value to a constant file instead of css and you could use `@eval` in `UIBinder`

Sample code:

```
<ui:style>
      @eval phoneDensity com.gwt.demo.client.Styles.INSTANCE.phoneDensity(); 
     .widget{ width: phoneDensity; }
</ui:style>
```

Please have a look at below posts. It might help to solve this issue with some alternative solution.

- [How can I use the same @def in multiple CssResource css files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284168/how-can-i-use-the-same-def-in-multiple-cssresource-css-files)
- [CssResource @def in UiBinder](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-web-toolkit/c8XdDoxDNZA/dWtkdAENYXMJ)